# Splitting string by new line with a condition

Tags: java, regex, newline

I am trying to split a String by `\n` only when it's not in my "action block".
Here is an example of a text `message\n [testing](hover: actions!\nnew line!) more\nmessage` I want to split when ever the `\n` is not inside the `[](this \n should be ignored)`, I made a regex for it that you can see here https://regex101.com/r/RpaQ2h/1/ in the example it seems like it's working correctly so I followed up with an implementation in Java:

```
final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
final Matcher matcher = NEW_LINE_ACTION.matcher(message);

String rest = message;
int start = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group("action") != null) continue;

    final String before = message.substring(start, matcher.start());
    if (!before.isEmpty()) lines.add(before.trim());

    start = matcher.end();
    rest = message.substring(start);
}

if (!rest.isEmpty()) lines.add(rest.trim());

return lines;
```

This should ignore any `\n` if they are inside the pattern showed above, however it never matches the "action" group, seems like when it is added to java and a `\n` is present it never matches it. I am a bit confused as to why, since it worked perfectly on the regex101.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://tio.run/##dVJNT8JAED3bXzEQD63REq8iGg8eSMCYgKe2JNsywsJ22@xOi0b97TjbDw4Se@jbvPdmXnemO1GLm916fzzKvCwMwY6JsCKpQoMb/AjngrItmrH3j/4qiNDoseeVVapkBpkS1sJcSA1fngf8dIIlQQx1IdeQs@wvyEi9iRIQZmMD5754l1ooaAVoAmACQ//xXmQkC/0Qx1G0iuMkueJXHPvRKnDHIPhmT2pQ7NkSxzoYjv80sy1wtxytFRtkF0SElhztMPG3RY3mDtosO2CHxgMoqXEQQF4YV9NVn/evUkuu/eUta73YTQfKDic9E2ZFXkqFfnPJ6xM9f5stp7Ppy3NwCug2wDNrcdJ3CzvGb@8WuNjRCJZbbL9GUkW4hlqoCuEglYIUISs08fCZ5wURWw3aShG7jBSpwrMdNOqkT@etl0pk@KSU34Q0qYtPS5iHRUVhyWWktN8WOtX9Aj@e93M8/gI?

Comment: @ctwheels Yes! That worked!

Comment: For reference, regex101 has a code generator. Makes your life a lot easier :) I just added the replacement of `$1` to ensure your strings keep the action (instead of check to see if the group was set and then doing it with code logic). Simpler, cleaner, and less likely to cause bugs.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you so much!

Comment: @ctwheels You should write an answer.

Comment: @hev1 probably a good idea since it's still unanswered, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking whether the group is `action`, you can simply use regex replacement with the group `$1` (the first capture group).

I also changed your regex to `(?<action>\[[^\]]*]\([^)]*\))|(?<break>\\n)` as `[^\]]*` doesn't backtrack (`.*?` backtracks and causes more steps). I did the same with `[^)]*`.

[See code working here](https://tio.run/##dVHdTsMgFL4eT3HWeAEmknhrrcYHWGKyy9IlrMOOjUIDp1Oje/ZKS6eJ0Rs@8v2cczgc5EneHHbHYdBt5zzCIRK8R224V4164yuJ9V75nPyjP0tE5W1OSNdvja6hNjIEWElt4YOQxcwGlBjh5PQO2qjRNXptm7IC6ZvAJuviRVtpICkwlYcCMvp4L2vUzj4IUZYbIarqOh5C0HLDxitjn9Gz9Uoeo0UIy7L8d7WQIJZrVQiyUdEGJaqAIz1iRffupPwdpGZhGR1WvYLRVi0ZtM6PmTkdG3x3mDcA3YzFheG1azttFJ2ewn5mmncaF5GwuGT5zNA0Lsv/2EroDcbE7Iy/0BlZqydjaHZ1m6XI@j2garnrkXcxhsbSFJzkMyHnYfgC)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String regex = "(?<action>\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\([^)]*\\))|(?<break>\\\\n)";
        final String string = "message\\n [testing test](hover: actions!\\nnew line!) more\\nmessage";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll("$1");

        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```